# Cropping and uploading image with Croppie jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

cropping and uploading image using  [Croppie plugin](http://demo.expertphp.in/crop-image-before-upload-using-croppie) working fine sample code as follows

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PHP and jQuery - Crop Image and Upload using Croppie plugin</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.2/croppie.js"></script>

  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <style>
  .croppie-container .cr-vp-circle
  {
    border-radius:0
  }
  .cr-slider-wrap
  {
    display:none
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="max-height: 500px;">
    <div class="card-header bg-info" style="display:none">PHP and jQuery - Crop Image and Upload using Croppie plugin</div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div id="upload-demo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding:5%;">
        <strong>Select image to crop:</strong>
        <input type="file" id="image">

        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-upload-image" style="margin-top:2%">Upload Image</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4" style="background: #9d9d9d;">
        <div id="preview-crop-image" style="background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 50px 72px;
    height: 200px;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


var resize = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    enableOrientation: true,    
    viewport: { // Default { width: 100, height: 100, type: 'square' } 
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        type: 'square' //square
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }
});


$('#image').on('change', function () { 
  var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      resize.croppie('bind',{
        url: e.target.result
      }).then(function(){
        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});


$('.btn-upload-image').on('click', function (event) {
  resize.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
  }).then(function (img) {
  alert(img)
    $.ajax({
      url: "cropping.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {"image":img},
      success: function (data) {
        html = '<img src="' + img + '" />';
        $("#preview-crop-image").html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

But the result from croppie plugin is getting as canvas i.e base64 but we want the result from croppie plugin as same as file upload so that we can access the cropped image with `$_FILES`, how it can be achieved please suggest us.

Answer (score 1):

Croppie is using `canvas.drawImage(...)` to manipulate images so you can not upload the images as you upload a file using a file input field. What you can do is, submit the base64 encoded string and reconstruct(base64 decode) the image in your server.

```
$imageName = $uuid.".png";

// extracting the base64 encoded string from the request payload
$imageArray = explode(";", $_POST['imagebase64']);
$imageContents = explode(",", $imageArray[1]);

$imagebase64 = base64_decode($imageContents[1]);

// saving the image to a temp file
$tempPath = sys_get_temp_dir()."/".$imageName;
file_put_contents($tempPath, $imagebase64);
```

Now you have the uploaded image saved in `$tempPath`